# TFS 2015 Update 3 Vnext build definition copies all artifacts except parent project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, tfs-2015

Attempting to build a multiple project solution with MSBuild ver 14.0 vNext with the following switches:
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:PackageLocation=$(build.stagingDirectory)

The solution contains projects like:
Project,
Project.Data,
Project.Model,
etc... (5 projects total)

Build appears to work fine including tests, with a few warnings and no errors, however, the drop folder contains output for all dependent projects, while omitting Project(the parent project).

Have been googling and attempting different configurations for many hours, any help would be appreciated.

Logs or sections of logs are available if they'll be helpful.

Comment: In the Publish Build Artifacts step,  did you set publish from $(build.stagingDirectory) to your drop folder? Did you check the $(build.stagingDirectory) folder on your build agent?

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT The build artifacts step is using the default configuration of Build.SourcesDirectory to the drop folder. The agent\_work\1\s directory (Build.SourcesDirectory) appears to contain files for all 5 projects. The agent\_work\1\a directory (Build.artifactsStagingDirectory contains files from only 4 of the 5 projects, as does the drop folder.

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT It appears that the project is being ignored in the Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) step of the build. All other projects are listed in the log, but there is no mention of the missing project at all. On the build server, _work\1\s is populated with the entire project, however it appears to be ignored during CopyFiles.

Comment: Can you share the entire logs?

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't misunderstood, you have checked that the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) contain all 5 projects that you need, but the "Copy Files" step, it doesn't copy all them to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory). In the "**Contents**" blank of "Copy Files" step, enter "*", this means copies all files in the root folder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Contents folder in the above example is actually **\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**, which as it turns out, is correct. For whatever reason, when the $(BuildConfiguration) is set to debug, although there are in errors in the build log, no bin files are created for that project. When the $(BuildConfiguration) is set to release, compiled bin files are created for all projects and the copy step works fine.

Comment: @absinc So you solved it by change the configuration to "Release". If so, could you please post you solution as an answer for this question.

Comment: Hi, and thanks again for your help. I don't know of a reason why this does not build a debug version of the bin file, it seems to work fine locally. I hesitate to mark this as a solution if its still not working correctly...